# Ungroup rows of arrays to two-column crosstabs (i.e. array_name, item)?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, scripting

How do I ungroup rows of arrays, (first item is the name, the rest are elements), to two-column [crosstabs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table)?

Input:

```
A S1 S2 S4 S6
B P1 J9
C W0 R7
```

Desired output :

```
A S1
A S2
A S4
A S6
B P1
B J9
C W0
C R7
```

Comment: I wouldn't call this convert column to row, but ungrouping rows. Just an opinion.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: There's got to be good duplicates of this. I know I've included how to do it as parts of more complicated answers, but not as an independent one...

Comment: Shell script hint: `while read` and `printf` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
awk '{for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) print $1, $i}' input
```